# How to use icons as the labels of piechart in MPandroidchart library

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am using mpandroidchart library to build a pie chart. The requirement for pie chart is that it should contain icons in each entry.

[image: image1]

In my case it is showing up the percentage of each entry values.
[image]

Is there any way to change the labels to icons?

**My Fragment class**

```
public class MonitorOverallFragment extends Fragment {
    private int[] CHART_COLORS = {Color.rgb(253,151,39), Color.rgb(103,63,180), Color.rgb(204,217,72), Color.rgb(44,152,240)};
    private Context mContext;
    private Activity mActivity;
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        mContext = context;
        icons1 = new Bitmap[]{BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(),
                R.drawable.ic_card_analitics_white),
                BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(),
                        R.drawable.ic_kredit_analitics_white),
                BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(),
                        R.drawable.ic_vklad_analitics_white),
                BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(),
                        R.drawable.ic_nps_analitics_white)};
    }

    public MonitorOverallFragment(){

    }

    int [] sampledata = {30, 40, 20, 10};

        Bitmap[] icons1;

    private String icons[] = {"a", "b", "c", "d"};



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,  ViewGroup container,  Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_monitor_overall, container, false);

        setUpPieChart(rootView);
        return  rootView;
    }
    private void setUpPieChart(View v){
        List<PieEntry> pieEntries = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 0; i<sampledata.length; i++){
            pieEntries.add(new PieEntry(sampledata[i], icons1[i]));
        }
        PieDataSet dataSet = new PieDataSet(pieEntries, "");
        dataSet.setColors(CHART_COLORS);
        PieData data = new PieData(dataSet);

        PieChart chart = (PieChart)v.findViewById(R.id.pie_monitor_overall);
        chart.setData(data);
        chart.setDrawEntryLabels(true);

        Description description = new Description();
        description.setText("");
        chart.setDescription(description);

        chart.invalidate();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a sample from my code :

```
Drawable user_icon = getDrawable(R.drawable.user);
myData = new ArrayList<>();
myData.add(new PieEntry(46, user_icon));
PieDataSet dataSet = new PieDataSet(myData, "");
PieData data = new PieData(dataSet);
pieChart.setData(data);
```

*(I know it's not well explained but since you're asking about icons then you're already over the simple implementation of the library)*

Please note that I'm using the version 3.0.2, this feature may have not been there in previous versions.

Comment: I tried to use the constructor Entry(x, y, drawable) for a LineChart, but it didn't works. I'm not able to display the icon at the position.
Should I set to true some options in the Chart ?

Comment: @BadrYousfi The 'setDrawValues' option must be enabled for icons to appear.