# How to use icons instead of labels in RadarChart of MPAndroidChart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I'm trying to put a radar chart in my Android application using [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) library.

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44863021/how-to-use-icons-as-the-labels-of-piechart-in-mpandroidchart-library) very similar question and tried that approach but it didn't work for me

Here's my code

```
RadarChart chart = findViewById(R.id.activity_family_member_detail_chart);
Drawable iconTotalEarnedPoints = getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_star_border);
Drawable iconEarnedMoney = getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_attach_money);
Drawable iconTextPosts = getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_message);
Drawable iconImagePosts = getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_photo_size_select_actual);
Drawable iconAudioPosts = getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_audiotrack);
List<RadarEntry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
entries.add(new RadarEntry(member.getTotalEarnedPoints(), iconTotalEarnedPoints));
entries.add(new RadarEntry(member.getEarnedMoney(), iconEarnedMoney));
entries.add(new RadarEntry(member.getTextPosts(), iconTextPosts));
entries.add(new RadarEntry(member.getImagePosts(), iconImagePosts));
entries.add(new RadarEntry(member.getAudioPosts(), iconAudioPosts ));

RadarDataSet radarDataSet = new RadarDataSet(entries, "");

RadarData radarData = new RadarData(radarDataSet);
chart.setData(radarData);
chart.getLegend().setEnabled(false);
chart.getDescription().setEnabled(false);
chart.getYAxis().setEnabled(false);
chart.animateXY(1000, 1000);
chart.invalidate();
```

What i am getting as a result is a radar that shows the correct values, but the labels are numbers (from 0 to 4) while instead of numbers i would like to have the specified drawables, how can i achieve that?